# Acortar múltiples condiciones en una sola para ver si una variable coincide con algún texto

Tags: php

¿Hay forma de acortar esto?

```
<?php if (($_SESSION['Particulos'] == "L")OR($_SESSION['Particulos'] == "E")) { } ?>
```

A algo tipo esto:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['Particulos'] == "L" OR "E") { } ?>
```

¿O tengo que escribir siempre el $Session?

he estado mirando en la página de PHP pero los ejemplos no me quedan nada claros.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<?php if( strpos("LE", $_SESSION['Particulos']) !== false ) { } ?>`

`strpos` busca la posición en el `string` "LE" donde se encuentra el valor de la variable `$_SESSION`, si no está retorna `false`.

Otra más corta, usando expresión regular:

`<?php if( preg_match("(L|E)", $_SESSION['Particulos']) ) { } ?>`

Bueno, casí. jajajaja.

Con array:

`<?php if( in_array( $_SESSION['Particulos'], ['L','E']) ) { } ?>`

Otro:

`<?php if( strpos("=LE", $_SESSION['Particulos']) ) { } ?>`

Comment: Me encanta, de momento es la que mas me convence

Comment: Editada, por otra supuesta mente más corta, jajajaja.

Comment: <?php if( strpos("=LE", $_SESSION['Particulos']) ) { } ?>   Esto es lo mas corto que pude reducirlo, como ves agregué un caracter "=" para evitar que retorne cero (0), de modo que ya no sea necesaria la comparación con false.

Comment: El caracteres que agregues al principio no puede ser igual a ningunas de las posibilidades que pueda tomar $_SESSION['Particulos']

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['Particulos'] == "L" || $_SESSION['Particulos'] == "E") {}?>
```

Esa es la forma mas corta que conosco!. Saludos

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['Particulos'] == "L" OR "E") { } ?>
```

Este metodo es imposible por que al momento de llamar la declaracion `OR` estamos "reiniciando" la peticion de lo que estamos buscando!. Significa que en este caso quedaria "E" como nulo o invalido.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    $copy=$_SESSION['Particulos'];//copiando a una variable


       if ($copy == "L" || $copy== "E") { }  //trabajamos solamente con la variable copy

?>
```

o con `switch` revisa: http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php

```
<?php 
        $copy=$_SESSION['Particulos'];//copiando a una variable
switch ($copy) {
    case "L":
        echo "es L";
        break;
    case "E":
        echo "es E";
        break;
}
?>
```